# How to pass array data to controller for storing data in the Pg database in rails, so that i can add multiple records at the same time in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
I'm not using rails form to submit my data. Im using javascript post method to stored the data to database in rails application
Here is the code i have written to send the data to database.
```

/app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:5 SectionsController#create:

```
     3: def create
     4:     params[:section].each do |data|
 =>  5:         binding.pry
     6:         # section_params = data
     7: 
     8:         @section = Section.new(params[:section] )
     9:         respond_to do |format|
    10:             if @section.save!
    11:                 format.html { redirect_to layout_path, notice: "Sections Created Successfully"    }
    12:                 format.js
    13:                 format.json { render json: @section,status: :created, location: @section}
    14:             else  
    15:                 
    16:                 # format.html { render :new, alert:"Unable to create new "}
    17:                 format.json { render json: @section.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    18:             end  
    19:         end
    20:     end
    21: end
```

**This is the output, that i have been getting in my Terminal**

[3] pry(#)> params
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"section"=>[<ActionController::Parameters {"sectiontitle"=>"section1", "description"=>"this is 0", "position"=>{"top"=>0, "left"=>0}, "height"=>248, "width"=>398, "layout_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>, <ActionController::Parameters {"sectiontitle"=>"section2", "description"=>"this is 1", "position"=>{"top"=>0, "left"=>400}, "height"=>248, "width"=>398, "layout_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>], "controller"=>"sections", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
[4] pry(#)> params[:section]
=> [<ActionController::Parameters {"sectiontitle"=>"section1", "description"=>"this is 0", "position"=>{"top"=>0, "left"=>0}, "height"=>248, "width"=>398, "layout_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>,
<ActionController::Parameters {"sectiontitle"=>"section2", "description"=>"this is 1", "position"=>{"top"=>0, "left"=>400}, "height"=>248, "width"=>398, "layout_id"=>"1"} permitted: false>]

Im getting my data to the controller in params

**this my show page, from where I'm sending my data using javascript**

```
container
    

.row          
        .col-md-7
            .p-3
                button#imageModalButton.btn.btn-primary type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#imageModal" <b>Design Layout</b>
                = link_to  "Preview", preview_layout_layout_path ,:class=>"btn btn-danger mx-3"
               

        .col-5.border-left
            .row
               .col-md-12
                  = text_field_tag 'search', nil, class: "form-control search col-11", placeholder: "Search.."
                  i.fa.fa-file-search
               = render 'media/groupingMedia'


                


#imageModal.modal.fade aria-hidden="true"  aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" role="dialog"  tabindex="-1"
  .modal-dialog.modal-lg role="document"
    .modal-content style="width:800px"
        
            .row.bg-dark
                .col-md-4 
                    button.btn.btn-outline-primary#add-section Add Section
                .col-md-4 
                    button.btn.btn-outline-success#save-layout Save
                .col-md-4 
                    button.btn.btn-outline-danger  data-dismiss="modal" type="button"  Cancel
        
            <div  class="d-flex " id="canvas" style="position:relative;background-color: black;height:500px; overflow:auto;"></div>



css:

    .section{
        height:250px;
        width :400px;
        opacity: 0.3;
    }


javascript: 
        let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
        let addSectionBtn = document.getElementById('add-section')
        canvas.className= "row"
        canvas.setAttribute("height","100%")
    
        var position 
        var dimension

        var count =1;

        addSectionBtn.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{

            let sectiondiv = document.createElement("div");
            let topdiv = document.createElement("div");
            let mediadiv = document.createElement("div");
            
            let closebtn = document.createElement("button");
            
            let p = document.createElement("p");
            let h3 = document.createElement("h3");

            h3.innerHTML = count
            
            sectiondiv.setAttribute("id","section"+count);

            closebtn.className ='btn btn-outline-danger close'
            closebtn.setAttribute("value","close"+count);

            sectiondiv.className = "border  section ui-widget-content"
            
            sectiondiv.appendChild(h3)
            sectiondiv.appendChild(p)
            sectiondiv.appendChild(topdiv)

            topdiv.className = "d-flex mx-1 p-2 justify-content-between"
            topdiv.appendChild(h3)
            topdiv.appendChild(p)

            mediadiv.setAttribute("id","media"+count)

            closebtn.setAttribute("id","close"+count)

            canvas.appendChild(sectiondiv)
            p.appendChild(closebtn);
            closebtn.innerHTML = 'X';
            $("#section"+count).resizable();
            $("#section"+count).draggable();


            let sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
            console.log (sections)

            for(var i=0;i<sections.length;i++){
                sections[i].addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
                    var id = event.target.id.split("section")[1]
                    console.log(id)
                
                    
                    // var pos_of_section = $("#section"+id).position()
                    //   console.log(pos_of_section+id)
                })
            }

            // logic to remove the section from the layout 
            let closebtns = document.querySelectorAll('.close');
            for(var i=0;i<closebtns.length;i++){
                closebtns[i].addEventListener('click',(event)=>{
                    var id=event.target.id.split("close")[1]
                    $("#section"+id).remove()
                })

            }
        
            count++
            
        })
        
        

        let savebtn = document.getElementById('save-layout')
        
       
        // Saving layout sections  using jquery
        savebtn.addEventListener('click',(event)=>{

            // setting logic to get the updated position and dimension of each section 
            var position = []
            var dimension = []  
            let allSections =[]
            let layout_id = window.location.href.split("/layouts/")[1]

            let sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section')
            sections.forEach((section)=>{
                position.push($("#"+section.id).position())
                dimension.push(($("#"+section.id).height())*$("#"+section.id).width())
                allSections.push(section.id)
                //console.log("height of :"+section.id,$("#"+section.id).height())
                //console.log("width of :"+section.id,$("#"+section.id).width())

            })
            
            storeData(allSections,position,dimension,layout_id);

            

            
        })

        function storeData(allSections ,position ,dimension,layout_id){
                
            //console.log("Position of each Section",position)
            //console.log("dimension of each sections",dimension)

            let data =[]
            // setting section data in data variable as objects 
            for(var i=0; i < allSections.length; i++){
                var height = $("#"+allSections[i]).height()
                console.log(height)
                var width = $("#"+allSections[i]).width()
                data.push({sectiontitle: allSections[i], description: "this is "+i, position: position[i], height: height, width: width, layout_id: layout_id})
            }

            console.log(data)
            options = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    section: data 
                    
                })
            }
           
            post('http://localhost:3000/sections',{section: data}).then((response)=>{
                console.log(response)
            }).catch((e)=>{
                console.log(e)
            })
            


            // fetch('http://localhost:3000/layouts', options)
            // .then(console.log)
            // .catch(console.log)


            // => Array of Objects representing Band objects with IDs set
        
            

        }


        // FetchWrapper by sajan Dhakal
        function get(url) {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                credentials: 'same-origin',
            };
            return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }
        function post(url, body) {
            var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'X-CSRF-Token': token },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            };
            return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }

        function put(url, body) {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'PUT',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            };
            return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }
        function patch(url, body) {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'PATCH',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            };
            return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }
        // prefixed with underscored because delete is a reserved word in javascript
        function _delete(url) {
            const requestOptions = {
                method: 'DELETE',
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            };
            return fetch(url, requestOptions).then(handleResponse);
        }
        // helper functions
        function handleResponse(response) {
            return response.text().then((text) => {
                try {
                    // console.log(text)
                    const data = text && JSON.parse(text);
                    if (!response.ok) {
                        
                        if (response.status === 401) {
                            const error = { code: response.status, detail: response.statusText };
                            return Promise.reject(error);
                        }
                        const error = {
                            code: (data && data.code) || response.status,
                            detail: (data && data.detail) || response.statusText,
                        };
                        return Promise.reject(error);
                    }
                    return data;
                } catch (e) {
                    const error = { code: 500, detail: 'something went wrong' };
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }
            });
        }
```

**This is my Section model**

```
  class Section < ApplicationRecord
        belongs_to :layout,dependent: :destroy
        has_many :media, through: :section_multimedia
        has_many :section_multimedia, dependent: :destroy
        
    end
```

**This is the error while trying to store data**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 25519ms (ActiveRecord: 5.3ms)



  
ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.):
  
app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:8:in `block in create'
app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:4:in `each'
app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:4:in `create'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mukesh, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Here is what you can do. Change the params of type `ActionController::Parameters` to a hash before initializing the Section. Maybe like this:

```
@section = Section.new(params[:section].to_h) #=> params[:section].to_h is a hash
```

More on this here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_hash

Also, I would create all the objects and then save them in the db to avoid any corrupted data. If you use Rails 6, you could use the insert_all method and pass an array of hashes. Like:

```
Section.insert_all(
  [
    section1,
    section2,
    ...
  ]
)
```

If you use Rails 5, you can use create with multiple hashes, like:

```
Section.create!((
  [
    section1,
    section2,
    ...
  ]
)
```

Keep also in mind that it is good practice to use [transactions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) to avoid corruption.